# can not get a type of DBGrid Column, free pascal

Tags: sql, lazarus, freepascal, invariants

I use a free pascal lazarus. I have `DBGrid` that loads table from DB. I created columns in designer and `sqlqueries` to these columns. Everything is excellent. But when i need to get type of field i get an error`: Project Admin raised exception class 'External: SIGSEGV'.` I do it like this:

```
var s:Variant;
  begin
    s:=Column.FieldName; // there is ok. I get right column name
    s:=Column.Field.FieldKind;//here i get an error
```

Thanks.

Comment: I think column.field is the corresponding field in the currently selected record. It might not be valid if the tdataset has no dataset (query) loaded.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. What does *and  `sqlqueries` to these columns* mean? Your code snippet has no context, so it's impossible to say why it's not working. Please provide a [mcve] that we can use to reproduce the issue.